# Strong and simple to implement encryption techniques in .NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, encryption, base64, aes

I am working over one my student project over .Net4 and MVC3.
Project is almost at completion except some security features such as Encoding/Decoding information for saving in config file such as Connection String etc.

I want to avoid a very complex solution and so I am looking for some easy to use Encryption technique in .NET ideally something where I can just provide a KEY and String and it gives me back the encoded text and vice versa (similar to the Base64 example given below).

I went through MSDN’s [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht.aspx) Namespace documentation online but it has a lot of options for a newbie like me I guess.

Kindly provide me with suggestions and path to follow to achieve it.
Thank you.

---

While searching I found a simple solution of Base64 which I implemented like this:

```
    static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
    {
        byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
        string encodedValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
        return encodedValue;
    }

    static public string DecodeFrom64(string toDecode)
    {
        var toDecodeAsString = System.Convert.FromBase64String(toDecode);
        string decodedValue = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(toDecodeAsString);
        return decodedValue;
    }
```

Works fine but the problem is as far as I’ve understood this is not something very reliable as a static encoding technique (one without a custom KEY) can be easily decoded and so many online base 64 decoders are available on net. I also tried to work with [AES as expalined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx) but failed to succeed.

Comment: Base64 isn't encryption, it's encoding. You should learn the difference before trying to implement serious cryptographic primitives. Anyway, the real answer is that no cipher is simple to implement - strong cryptography and simplicity are almost mutually exclusive by definition.

Comment: What are you trying to encrypt? User content or configuration data?

Comment: Be careful not to confuse **Encoding** with **Encrypting**. The first has nothing to do with security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **maximum** simplicity just have a look at Windows' Data Protection API ([DAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx)). This will provide encryption **without** requiring you to handle the keys.

You can easily use this with the [`ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class provided in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple example **[Simple String Encryption and Decryption with Source Code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/simplestringencryption.aspx)**